# Use static variables instead of using argparse in googleapiclient - Python

Tags: python, google-search-api

I'm just started working with the Google Search Analytics API main [sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/searchconsole/search_analytics_api_sample.py) for python.

I would like to go further ahead and pass static variables to sample_tools.init() instead of being asked for them in the command-line interface.

In which way can I add these parameters and pass to sample_tools.init()?

> start_date = '2015-10-20' start_date = '2015-10-21' var_uri =
>   'http://www.example.com'

```
import argparse
import sys
from googleapiclient import sample_tools

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('property_uri', type=str,
                       help=('Site or app URI to query data for (including '
                             'trailing slash).'))
argparser.add_argument('start_date', type=str,
                       help=('Start date of the requested date range in '
                             'YYYY-MM-DD format.'))
argparser.add_argument('end_date', type=str,
                       help=('End date of the requested date range in '
                             'YYYY-MM-DD format.'))

def main(argv):
    service, flags = sample_tools.init(
        argv, 'webmasters', 'v3', __doc__, __file__, parents=[argparser],
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly')

    request = {
        'startDate': flags.start_date,
        'endDate': flags.end_date,
        'dimensions': ['page', 'query'],
        'rowLimit': 50
    }
    response = execute_request(service, flags.property_uri, request)
    print_table(response, 'Top Queries')
```

Answer (score 2):

It was quite easy, I just removed the argparser from the array and leave it blank and then define the variables.

```
def main(argv):
    service, flags = sample_tools.init(
        argv, 'webmasters', 'v3', __doc__, __file__, parents=[],
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly')

    start_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(
        datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=4), '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(
        datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=3), '%Y-%m-%d')

    property_uri = 'http://www.bmimedia.net'

    #Create the request. Use the API tutorial to explain how the API works
    request = {
        'startDate': end_date,
        'endDate': end_date,
        'dimensions': ['page', 'query'],
        'rowLimit': 10
    }

    response = execute_request(service, property_uri, request)
    print_table(response, 'Top Queries', end_date)
```

Comment: Even `argv` can be substituted by `[]` and `parents=[]` can be removed from the `sample_tools.init` args.